# Git switching branch policy in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, branch, git-branch

I have created two branches for a project I'm working on with git in IntelliJ. The first branch (A) I was working on modifying a file (call it A.Java). When I switched to second branch (B) with IntelliJ checkout, after modifying A.java under branch A, the file resulted to have the same modification in B that I was doing only under A!

This policy doesn't seems normal to me, since when I'm working in A I don't want to affect other branches. Where is the problem? Is a git behavior or it is only in IntelliJ?

Comment: Did you commit the file before you checked out branch B?

Comment: I retire my previous comment: I had a problem with previous commit and wasn't executed. When I commit and push on the right branch this behavior disappear. But I think is not very safe behavior. It exists a "strict mode" to avoid switching branches even if you haven't committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not commit the changes on branch A before checking out branch B then that behavior is normal. 
If you did commit the changes on branch A then created and switched to branch B then the changes should also show up in B (eg. you did `git checkout b -b`)

Comment: When I commit and push on the right branch this behavior disappear. But I think is not very safe behavior. It exists a "strict mode" to avoid switching branches even if you haven't committed?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526279/git-allows-for-branch-change-with-unstaged-changes) post from a while ago that might clarify

Comment: So as I understand, to avoid this behavior it is sufficient just to do one commit just after creating branch, right?

Comment: No. Doing a commit just after creating a branch does not affect this behavior.

Comment: If I do an initial commit in a brand new branch, then trying to switch to another branch, Intellij blocks me. So it works.