# Eclipse Egit Not Updating Source Code on Switch

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am attempting to setup a new Eclipse environment to work on an existing project that is stored in BitBucket.

I am able to clone the BitBucket repository & checkout two branches (master & develop).

With the two branches in my local repository, I'm having the following issue:
- Switch to develop
- Change a file (e.g. ContentHandler.java)
- Switch to master
- There are no warnings about uncommitted changes being lost
- The changes I made to the file are still visible after I've switched to Master

I had previously been able to use Eclipse & Egit on this project; however, I'm setting up a new dev machine and can't seem to get past the above issue.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

FYI: 
- Used Egit "Clone Existing Repository" to clone the repo
- Used File->Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **HEAD revision** of the modified file belongs to the **same commit in both branches** this is the **expected behavior of Git** (it is not Eclipse-specific and a feature, not a bug).

Only if an edited file has also to be changed due to switching branches, the edit has to be discarded, committed or stashed before switching.

See also [*Git allows for branch change with unstaged changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8526279/6505250)